# How to animate divs in on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering how this technic is done within JavaScript. When I scroll down the page, like this one: https://www.shift.agency, the content will be animated from bottom to top, when div is in viewport.

I think the code should know the following:

- Height of the target elements
- The start position of each section
- Scroll position relative to the window viewport

And I thought I should use offset, to get the height of the element?
I came up with the very basics if I am right:

```
// Scroll function
$(window).scroll(function() {

            var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();
            console.log(windowPos);
            $('.main section').each(function() { 
                var el = $(this);

            });

        });
```

Live code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPgaoq

Comment: You aren't doing anything.

Comment: So you are on the right track. Go ahead. You can do it. Google Search for Animation using Scroll Position and you are guided better.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few search terms that will get you where you want to go with this. I see two major effects happening on the site you linked.

#### Parallax

The first effect is called Parallax - it's a visual effect that provides artificial depth to your elements. It uses the concept that as the point of perspective changes vertically, objects closer to you will appear to move up more quickly than objects further away. There are quite a few jQuery plugins that will help you get acquainted with the effect. The most accessible is probably skrollr (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)

#### Waypoints

The second effect is the one you see where divs seem to animate onto screen as you reach a certain scroll-point. This is done directly through watching the scroll position and offset positions of trigger elements. Again there are quite a few jQuery plugins that help to configure this and automate the process. One that's fairly easy to implement is jQuery Waypoints (https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints).

Check those out and hopefully you'll be heading down the right path :) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As many mentioned you can use something like waypoints or skrollr. If your looking for animation when page is scrolled into viewport I would suggest checking out wow.js because skrollr is pretty in-depth. http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/. The example website is using a feature similar to what you could do in wow.js by adding the following code:

```
<div class="wow fadeInUp"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, WOW is very easy to use for simple effects and has some great built-ins. As you move further into effects and understanding how the process works, moving quickly into something like Skrollr will quickly heighten you sense of how the effect can be used and tailored to your needs.